# How to order posts in an arbitrary order?

Tags: posts, loop, query-posts

I need to list posts in a very specific order that has nothing to do with the date of the posts or the title, or anything WordPress can figure out for me. I need this order to be used when I list posts in a category and on the category archive page itself.

Is it possible to do something like this, were $idlist was an array of post ids in the order I want, and it could loop through each one?

```
  <?php query_posts(post_id=$idlist); ?>
  <?php the_permalink(); ?> etc...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, [`query_posts` is terrible](http://www.slideshare.net/andrewnacin/you-dont-know-query-wordcamp-netherlands-2012) doesn't use it. It does all kinds of fun things like mess up the very useful conditional tags like `is_singular` and the like as well as mess up pagination.

Short of hooking into the `posts_orderby` filter and writing some custom order by SQL, your best bet is to use the [`post__in` argument](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Post_.26_Page_Parameters) combined with the [`post__in` orderby](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters) argument that was added in WP 3.5.

Example:

```
<?php
$custom_query = new WP_Query(array(
    'post__in'  => array(1, 2, 4, 5, /* whatever your post ID's are here */),
    'orderby'   => 'post__in',
));

while ($custom_query->have_posts()) {
    $custom_query->the_post();
    // use the normal template tags here
    ?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
    <?php
}

// restore the original query
wp_reset_query();
```

Comment: Perfect. I put my final code in a [gist](https://gist.github.com/Shelob9/5078389) for my own benefit and in case anyone is interested.